# Two h:form creating issue to display h:messages

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm using a Richfaces popup window in my page and the corresponding code is  added below(Its a demo code only with Two textbox and Button):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions">

<f:metadata>
    <f:event listener="#{loginBean.verifyLogged}" type="preRenderView" />
    <f:event listener="#{cfsBean.fetchAllRFSList}" type="preRenderView" />
</f:metadata>

<h:body>

    <ui:composition template="../templates/home-template.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">
            <ui:include src="CfsGroupFeature-Add.xhtml">
                <ui:param name="parentBean" value="#{cfsBean}" />
            </ui:include>
            <h:form id="viewCfs">
                <rich:panel
                    style="border-width: 1px; border-color: #6B489D; padding:30px;width:145%; ">
                    <h:messages style="color:red;margin:8px;" />

                    <br />

                    <h:panelGrid columns="3">

        Enter your username :

        <h:inputText id="username" value="" size="20" required="true"
                            label="UserName">
                            <f:validateLength minimum="5" maximum="10" />
                        </h:inputText>

                        <h:message for="username" style="color:red" />

        Enter your age :
        <h:inputText id="age" value="" size="20" required="true" label="Age">
                            <f:validateLongRange for="age" minimum="1" maximum="200" />
                        </h:inputText>

                        <h:message for="age" style="color:red" />

                    </h:panelGrid>

                    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="result" />

                </rich:panel>
            </h:form>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I included the popup window inside this page but it's not part of the current page `h:form`, since I have two different `h:form` for both the windows.

But I get a weird issue if I try to remove `h:form` from the popup window: an error message will display to the parent page, while otherwise it's displayed in the popup page only.

What am I doing wrong here? Can someone please help me?

**EDIT:-**

popupWIndow Code

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions">


    <ui:define name="title">Page title</ui:define>



     <h:form>/** Some Components**/</h:form>

</ui:composition>
```

Comment: 2 upvotes within 5 views on a question with a code dump which is not in MCVE format at all? (so no one can reproduce your problem by copy'n'paste'n'running it) What's happening here?

Comment: Please add you popup Window code as well,May be anyone can help you

Comment: And stating _"code is something like this:"_ in the first sentence does not help either... It immediately scares me away since I'm not sure if the code that is posted (even if to little) is the code that is actually used.

Comment: @BalusC I am newbie so not aware about term and condition of posting a question.But i tried to add minimum code only

Comment: @Kukeltje dont scare from a newbie in stackoverflow its could be some mistake by me but why u scared?

Comment: If you are new, Stackoverflow suggested to read [ask]. There is (almost) al the info you need to post a good question. Including a reference to [mcve].

Comment: @SubodhJoshi Added popup code as you asked. When i am adding h:form message showed in popup window while this error happened in parent window when i am removing h:form from popup then things working fine.

Comment: Even if you are a newbie on stackoverflow, you are a developer and if you think like a developer while proof-reading your own question, don't you get strange feelings when reading _"code is **something** like this"_? Maybe I should not have used 'scares me away' but 'drives me away' or 'makes me stop reading the question'. Result is the same: Me not trying to give help...